# How do I handle and return a human readable error in a Java Azure Function app?

Tags: error-handling, azure-functions

How do I handle and return a human readable error in a Java Azure Function app?

All examples of this on a Google search, are just simple instructions on how to do a try-catch, which is not my question.

**More specfically, how do we design the return status code and the response body of the request, in a way that provides the most flexibility to a wide array of situations?**

Given that we are not integrating Spring-Boot in this case, and that we do not have access to anything Spring.

Given that my API generally returns an object that we will call `Pojo1`, on error, what is the best way to return a informative message.

NOTE: Of course, I do know there are situations where you want security through obscurity, in which case I would probably choose logging errors to app insights.  This is not my question though.

Answer (score 0):

- Well, you can set custom headers while returning the request. This
  can be done using a `setHeader` function.
- You can also use azure service bus or event grid which will carry
  specific messages regarding the errors.
- Also, you can use azure monitoring which collect all the error and
  notify you when everything happens.

Refer this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-custom-http-header#:%7E:text=To%20set%20a%20header%2C%20we%27ll%20use%20the%20setHeader,3.%20Set%20Header%20on%20Request%20%E2%80%93%20Before%204.3) by Eugen Paraschiv for indepth explanation on how to use setheader.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) on azure service bus and this [documentation](https://www.bing.com/search?q=azure%20event%20grid&cvid=840b39e4f9d1425fbf684b0f98d67530&aqs=edge.0.0l6j69i60l3.4367j0j1&pglt=2083&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531) on event grid.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) on azure monitoring logs.

Comment: This is how I would do it IF I need security through obscurity, by logging errors to a private secure location.    That isn't my question though.